# foreach looping in multidimension array in php

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here is my PHP code:

```
 $marks = array(
    'Mohammad' => array('Phisics' => 50, 'Math' => 80),
    'Arif'     => array('Phisics' => 55, 'Math' => 95),
```

);

Now I want to get the Mohammad and Arif's marks with subject using foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested `foreach` loop:

```php
foreach ($marks as $name => $subjects) {
    foreach ($subjects as $subjectName => $subjectMark) {
        echo "${name}'s mark for ${subjectName} is ${subjectMark}.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$marks = array(
    'Mohammad' => array('Phisics' => 50, 'Math' => 80),
    'Arif'     => array('Phisics' => 55, 'Math' => 95),
);

foreach ($marks as $key=>$names) {
    echo "--$key Marks-- <br/>";
    foreach ($names as $key=>$value) {
      echo "$key:$value <br/>";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
--Mohammad Marks--
Phisics:50
Math:80
--Arif Marks--
Phisics:55
Math:95
```